# TMemo: Find and copy a word that is between two words

Tags: delphi

to search for a word in a TMemo, I use:

```
var
   lineNumber: integer;
begin
   for lineNumber: = 0 to memo.lines.count-1 do
     if Pos ('my target', memo.lines [lineNumber])> 0 then
       ShowMessage ('Found in line' + IntToStr (lineNumber)); 
end;
```

I want to find and copy a word that is between two words:

***Example:***
Here is a line of text:
 **Nom: Amélie         Prénom : Gauthier**
I want to find and copy the word (or expression) that is between:
"**Nom:**" and "**Prénom**"  , that is to say "**Amélie**"

The word to be found is not always known.

How to do it please?
Thank you

Comment: Firstly, there is no need to iterate all lines of `TMemo`, it is enough to use its property `Text`. Secondly, use [Copy routine](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.Copy) to copy part of string. Thirdly, is the word to be found *always known*?

Comment: the word to found is not always known.

Comment: Search for the first word. When found, continue the search for the last word. Use the position of these two locations to copy the result. See `System.Pos` or `PosEx` to learn how to continue the search from a specific location.

Comment: I would strongly recommend switching to `TRichEdit` for this. You can use its [`FindText()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TCustomRichEdit.FindText) method to search for the desired words in the RichEdit's internal text buffer without having to extract any lines/substrings to `string` variables. Once you have the positions of the two words, you can highlight the text between them using the `SelStart`+`SelLength` properties, then extract the selected text to a `string` variable using the `SelText` property.  No need to waste memory unnecessarily on `string` operations

Comment: @  LU RD :thank you, it's a good idea.

Comment: @  Remy : thank you,  I wrote a simple solution that works well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have Regular Expressions to facilitate text searches.

This RegExp will return all the first names in your TMemo, between Nom: and Prénom:

```
uses System.RegularExpressions;

...
...

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var regEx: TRegEx;
    match: TMatch;
begin
  regEx.Create('Nom *: *(?<FirstName>.+) *Prénom *:');

  for match in regEx.Matches(Memo1.Lines.Text) do 
    ShowMessage(match.Groups.Item['FirstName'].Value);
end;
```